# Map only matching Half of the Key contained in a Struct

Tags: c++, dictionary, struct

I am currently attempting to use a struct to contain a coordinate (x,y) and have been running into the problem of my map declared `map<coordinate, bool>` where coordinate is the position and bool is whether it is filled or not.

My Struct:

```
typedef struct coordinate {
    int x;
    int y;
    friend bool operator>(const coordinate c1, const coordinate c2) {
        return c1.x > c2.x;
    }
    friend bool operator<(const coordinate c1, const coordinate c2) {
        return c1.x < c2.x;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const coordinate c1) {
        os << "(" << c1.x << "," << c1.y << ")";
        return os;
    }
    friend bool operator==(const coordinate c1, const coordinate c2) {
        return c1.x == c2.x && c1.y == c2.y;
    }
} coordinate;
```

and the method that I am using `map::find` in:

```
bool Board::Insert(int playerID, int x, int y){
    if(x > M || y > M){
        outOfBoundsError();
        return false;
    }
    else if(playerMap.find(playerID) != playerMap.end()){
        cout << "Player with ID " << playerID << " already exists\n";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        coordinate pos;
        pos.x = x;
        pos.y = y;

        if(gameMap.find(pos) == gameMap.end()){
            Player newPlayer = Player(playerID, pos);
            gameMap[pos] = true;
            playerMap[playerID] = pos;
            N++;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Player already exists at position " << pos << "\n";
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing something simple such as an operator overload that needs to be done, but I cannot find how the values are being compared in the `map::find` function.

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need `typedef struct`.

Comment: map uses < to compare keys (by default). And only <. It doesn't use ==

Comment: So your question is “How is `std::map` finding my keys?”?